# How to make SQL query when you have multiple if conditions

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to build an API that supports, list, search, and filters. I am not sure where to put the `where` clause.

It works in some cases but doesn't in many. For example, when input body has search filed it will work but when you apply only the second filter which is `pan` in this case it didn't.

```
const query = {
    text: `
      select master.contact.id,
      master.contact.name
      from
      master.contact
       `
  };
  if (input.search) {
    query.text += ` where
    (master.contact.pan ILIKE '${input.search}%' or master.contact.ira ILIKE '${input.search}%')`;
  }

  if (input.filters) {
    const {
      isActive,
      pan
    } = input.filters;
    if (isActive !== undefined) {
      query.text += ` where master.contact.isActive = ${isActive}`;
    }

    if (pan) {
      query.text += `and master.contact.pan = ${pan}`;
    }
```

Comment: You might try looking for an existing ORM rather than attempting to conditionally build the sql statements yourself. The typical pattern is you can build up a "data structure" based on your conditions and then it's the job of such a library to convert that "data structure" into the actual SQL statement sent to the server. In short, people have already invented things to do this, so there is little point inventing it **again** yourself.

Comment: Google search; https://www.google.com/search?q=node+js+orm+postgres and research the results.

Comment: @NeilLunn: this is an old project, Introducing ORM at this stage would take a lot of effort and time. I have no choice I have to complete it in this way

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this. One of them would be to have

```
Where 1=1
```

In you main query. So you can add And condition for every condition you have.

```
const query = {
text: `
  select master.contact.id,
  master.contact.name
  from
  master.contact
  where 1=1
  `
}; 

If (input.search) { 
  query.text += ` and (master.contact.pan ILIKE '${input.search}%' or master.contact.ira ILIKE '${input.search}%')`;
}
```

And so on...